# CrawlSpider only crawls start_urls

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

All, I try to build a spider which will crawl the sherdog website and give me the profile of all fighters (name, birthdate, height, nationality). If I run the spider it parses the start_urls fine. The problem is that the crawlspider will not start crawling, so I end up with only 2 parsed items. I read the doc's but also new to Scrapy so I might miss something. You have any idea what? The website uses relative url's so I first thought that might be the issue, but after building the absolute url's it still didnt work. I really hope you guys can help me out!

```
class ProfileSpyder(CrawlSpider):
  name = "Profile"
  allowed_domains = ["http://www.sherdog.com/fighter/"]
  start_urls = ["http://www.sherdog.com/fighter/Daniel-Cormier-52311", 
            "http://www.sherdog.com/fighter/Ronda-Rousey-73073"]

  Rules = (
      Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/fighter/')), callback='parse_item', follow=True)      
      )

  def parse_item(self, response):
    #Build absolute urls and sent new requests
    for href in   response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/section[2]/div"):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)       
    #Parse item                     
    item = FighterProfile()
    item['Name'] =   response.xpath('.//section/div/h1/span[@class="fn"]/text()').extract()
    item['Birthdate'] = response.xpath('.//section/div/div/div/div/div/div/span/span[@itemprop="birthDate"]/text()').extract()
    item['Height'] = response.xpath('.//section/div/div/div/div/div/div/span[@class="item height"]/strong/text()').extract()
    item['Nationality'] = response.xpath('.//section[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]/strong/text()').extract()
    yield item
```

And the log:

```
2015-12-07 18:15:11 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: ufcfights)
2015-12-07 18:15:11 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2015-12-07 18:15:11 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'ufcfights.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'items.csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['ufcfights.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'ufcfights', 'USER_AGENT': 'Chrome/46.0.2490.80', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1.0}
2015-12-07 18:15:12 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-12-07 18:15:12 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-12-07 18:15:12 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-12-07 18:15:12 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2015-12-07 18:15:12 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-12-07 18:15:12 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-12-07 18:15:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-12-07 18:15:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sherdog.com/fighter/Daniel-Cormier-52311> (referer: None)
2015-12-07 18:15:13 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sherdog.com/fighter/Ronda-Rousey-73073> (referer: None)
2015-12-07 18:15:14 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-12-07 18:15:14 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 452,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 46874,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 7, 17, 15, 14, 92000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 7, 17, 15, 12, 618000)}
 2015-12-07 18:15:14 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Sure! Included it. The only thing that stands out is the 'ignoring link' part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override the `parse` method when using a `CrawlSpider`, it uses `parse` internally for the rules. Check the warning [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules)

Just change the callback method on the rules.

Comment: I changed the parse method for parse_item (3x: callback, def, request) The spider will run but no items are parsed, not even the start_urls. Weird, isnt it? Some other suggestions? I updated the log also.

Comment: I think you have a typo on the `Rules`, it should be `rules`

Comment: Never saw that one! However, now I get the following Error:               File "C:\Users\Jan Willem\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\crawl.py", line 83, in _compile_rules
    self._rules = [copy.copy(r) for r in self.rules]
exceptions.TypeError: 'Rule' object is not iterable
2015-12-09 21:32:08 [twisted] CRITICAL:

Comment: rules need to be a list, or a tuple, add a `,` at the end of every rule, or change `()` by `[]` on `rules`

Comment: Hi eLRuLL, thanks for your responses. I included the ',' after the 'Rule', but unfortunately it didnt work. The problem is that the log is not showing any error's and the output I get is just an empty csv file. The only new log-line I get is: DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.sherdog.com': <GET http://www.sherdog.com/fighter/Fabricio-Werdum-8390>. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Remove allowed_domains or change the string to sherdog.com

Comment: Works when I removed allowed_domains! Thanks a lot! Why did this work? Is it because it couldnt find any url because all of them are relative?

Comment: The domain is sherdog.com not http://www.sherdog.com, removing allowed_domains makes your spider work with every domain

Comment: please remember to accept if this  answer helped you!